# How to get Java to show the day of month from a date?

Tags: java

I am trying to extract the day of month of today's date. I have this

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, date.getDay());
```

but when the message dialog appears it show the number `5`
and today it's the `8`th. How can I set it to show what day of the month it is?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date.getDay()` returns the day of the week. sunday is 0 and similarly saturday is 6.

Please see the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29)

As per the comment given below

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String dayOfMonthStr = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
    System.out.println(dayOfMonthStr);
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that in Java API, but is there a way to show the actual day?

Comment: actual day means what?

Comment: Sorry, It means like today the 8th or tomorrow the 9th etc.. Not Monday, Tuesday etc.. I hope I'm explaining myself well.

Comment: @AndresRivera you want actually day of the month,see my updated answer

Comment: So it's not possible with the Date class? I have to use Calender right?

Comment: @AndresRivera getDate() in date returns the day of the month but its deprecated.I would suggest you not to use deparacted methods.Please go for calender

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40859/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-andres-rivera)

Comment: @AndresRivera, `So it's not possible with the Date class?`, yes its possible.

Comment: @camickr I have replied him by using getDate() but its deprecated

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to use getDate(), see my answer.

Comment: If I wanted to use the getDate() how would I get it to show the actual day of the month?

Comment: @AndresRivera date.getDate() will give you date of the month

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

You started to use the SimpleDateFormat class, but didn't do anything with it. Try:

```
System.out.println( new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format( new Date() ) );
System.out.println( new SimpleDateFormat("d").format( new Date() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()             // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region, that region represented by the JVM’s current default time zone.
         .getDayOfMonth()   // Extract the day-of-month. Returns an `int`.
```

## java.time

> extract the day of month of today's date

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Interrogate the `LocalDate` for [its day-of-month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfMonth()).

```
int dayOfMonth = today.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

UPDATE: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. I am leaving this section intact as history.

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 in Java 7…

```java
org.joda.time.DateTime theEighth = new org.joda.time.DateTime( 2013, 11, 8, 18, 0 ); // Default time zone.
System.out.println( "theEighth: " + theEighth );
System.out.println( "dayOfMonth of theEighth: " + theEighth.dayOfMonth().getAsText() );
```

When run…

```
theEighth: 2013-11-08T18:00:00.000-08:00
dayOfMonth of theEighth: 8
```